# Send multiple data (text and images) to a server through a socket

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

I've made a test server in python, which receives a connection through  a socket and save png files. But, I want to pass some other data to the server like the file's name, user who send it, etc. But I can't do this, because to receive the data you must inform the number of bytes you are reading in buffer.

I've researched a lot, some examples says to use struct and pack all data, but the size of one image to another is different and I can't simply make a struct format, because it will be different for each file I receive.

This is what I have working so far:

#### SERVER

```
import socket
import os
import sys

FilePath = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("localhost",8000))
s.listen(5) #Tipo, 5 conexoes no maximo {ao mesmo tempo}

i=0
name = 'file_'
while (True):
    sc, address = s.accept()
    name = 'file_%s' % i
    f = open(os.path.join(FilePath,'server_received/%s.png'% name) ,'wb') #open as binary data
    i=i+1
    # receives and writes the file
    l = sc.recv(1024)
    while (l):
        f.write(l)
        l = sc.recv(1024)
f.close()


sc.close()
s.close()
```

#### CLIENT

```
class SendToServer(Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, *args, **kwargs):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def run(self):
        try:
            while not self.queue.empty():
                s = socket.socket()
                s.connect((HOST,PORT))
                file_path = self.queue.get()
                file = open(file_path,'rb')
                s.send(file_path)
                l = file.read(1024)
                while l:
                    s.send(l)
                    l = file.read(1024)
                self.queue.task_done()
                s.close()
                print u"Enviado"
        except:
            print u"Sem conexao"

        #This i Use when I call the Thread:
        sync= SendToServer(queue)
        sync.run()
```

This code above is working well, but how can I send more data than just the file? (binary data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you taken a look at 'pickle'. With pickle you can serialize an object say you create an object say a dictionary:

```
    imageDict = {'imageFile': image, 'user': userName, 'fileName': file}

    pickleData = pickle.dumps(imageDict)

    s.send(pickleData)
```

now on your server you can unpickle the data:

```
l = sc.recv(1024)

imageDict = pickle.dumps(l)
```

Now as long you wait until all the data has been received you should have a dictionary just like the one you created on the client side.

Example in the interpreter:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> data = {'mac':4, 'mid':5}
>>> data
{'mac': 4, 'mid': 5}
>>> dataPickle = pickle.dumps(data)
>>> dataPickle
"(dp0\nS'mac'\np1\nI4\nsS'mid'\np2\nI5\ns."
>>> unpick = pickle.loads(dataPickle)
>>> unpick
{'mac': 4, 'mid': 5}
>>>
```

Comment: jramirez, this solution raises an TypeError, because you can't pickle file objects.

Comment: You can't pickle file objects you need to pickle the contents of the file. `pickle.dumps(file.read())` try this it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it using marshal(http://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html#module-marshal).

So, I've created a dict with all data in it (username, file_name, bynary file) I saved it in a file (marshal do that), then I transferred to the server all the binary file.

#### Client:

```
    while not self.queue.empty():
        try:
            s = socket.socket()
            s.connect((HOST,PORT))
        except:
            print "connection error"
            break
        file_path = self.queue.get()
        file = open(file_path,'rb')
        dados = ['User',
                'someothertext',
                file_path,
                file.read()
                ]
        temp = open(os.path.join(SaveDirectory,'temp'),'wb')
        marshal.dump(dados,temp)
        temp.close()
        file = open(os.path.join(SaveDirectory,'temp'),'rb')
        l = file.read(1024)
        while l:
            try:
                s.send(l)
                l = file.read(1024)
            except:
                print "error while sending"
                break


        temp.close()
        file.close()

        os.remove(os.path.join(SaveDirectory,'temp'))

        self.queue.task_done()

        s.close()
        print u"OK"
```

#### Server:

```
#coding: utf-8
import socket
import os
import sys
import marshal
FilePath = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("localhost",8000))
s.listen(5) #Tipo, 5 conexoes no maximo {ao mesmo tempo}

i=0
nome = 'file_'
while (True):
    sc, address = s.accept()
    nome = 'file_%s' % i
    temp = open(os.path.join(FilePath,'server_received/%s'% nome) ,'wb')
    i=i+1
    l = sc.recv(1024)
    while (l):
        temp.write(l)
        l = sc.recv(1024)
    temp.close()
    temp = open(os.path.join(FilePath,'server_received/%s'% nome) ,'rb') #abrir como binario
    #Here I can unpack my dictionary.
    dados = marshal.load(temp)
    temp.close()
    #removing the file I received
    os.remove(os.path.join(FilePath,'server_received/%s'% nome))
    print dados[0], dados[1], dados[2]
    arq  = open(os.path.join(FilePath,'server_received/%s'% dados[2].split('\\')[-1]),'wb')
    arq.write(dados[3])
    arq.close()


sc.close()
s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what about your protocol, do you want to write or not, but i have a good expereience:

use more one port:

**NOTE:** use UDP for more speed.

1. port number xxx for send your protocol commands
2. port number yyy for send your data transfer
3. port number zzz for receive your data transfer
4. port number uuu for ack your protocol commands

no 1 and 4 are releted together, no 3 and 2 are related together.

You can implement a system for send/ack for your command instead of using `TCP` protocol , because you have big data(picture), At another hand, you should want to use safe , So you can implement a set of command/ack over `UDP` that work like `TCP` but very light.

You should apply your system for number 1 and 4 , and don't apply for no 2 and 3.

Comment: UDP won't give you more speed; it will only change how the system reacts to a dropped packet.  (with UDP you'll simply lose the data in that packet; with TCP the packet will be automatically retransmitted)  Also with UDP you don't get any congestion management, which means that a UDP-based system under significant network load will often perform  poorly compared to a TCP-based system under load.

Comment: When you have voice , or big data, you are forced to use UDP and forget TCP and its handshaking, its handshaking is time consuming.

Comment: Voice, yes, since having a dropped packet of live audio retransmitted doesn't do you any good, as the retransmitted packet will arrive too late anyway.  I'm not sure why big data would benefit.  As for the TCP handshaking, that's generally a non-issue, since you only have to do it once at the beginning of the session, and then you can keep the TCP connection open indefinitely with no further handshaking required.